# Most of object baking black? (2.8)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, shaders

I have this model that I'm trying to bake to a texture:

[image]

But when I bake it, I get mostly black except for one diagonal brown square, like this:

[image]

I'm not quite sure what the issue is here. I'm using diffuse shader, when I'm using the glossy shader nothing shows up. Is there some reason why it's missing most of the model?

Here's the blender file: [image]

Comment: Could you attach your .blend please by uploading it to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and adding the link to your question?

Comment: Just attached the file